# How to convert improper fraction to mixed number?

Tags: python-3.x

If I have user input numerator and denominator where num = input for numerator and den = input for denominator how would the rest of the code go to convert an improper fraction to a mixed number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of floor division and modulo division.

```
num = int(input("Type numerator: "))
den = int(input("Type denominator: "))
whole_part = num // den
fract_part = num % den
print("Result: {} and {}/{}".format(whole_part, fract_part, den))
```

Comment: you forgot the fractional remainder.

Comment: My bad, I translated "mixed number" to "float" in my head. I'll edit.

Comment: It's coming out as a decimal no fractions

Comment: And result just ended the string

Comment: @user5281155 Try it with the edits.

Comment: Thank you. I have been trying everything. You saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Look at integer division in python // and the modulus function %.

```
num = int(input("Type numerator: "))
den = int(input("Type denominator: "))

integral_part = num // den
fractional_part_num = num % den

if fractional_part > 0:
    print("result: %s %s/%s" % 
          (integral_part, fractional_part_num, den))
else:
    print("result: %s" % integral_part)
```

Comment: Should be using string substitution like @weirdev here.. his way is the new improved way.

Comment: Can I give you a thumbs up?

Comment: Press the up arrow above the number on the top left of the answer.   But, I'd like to think I answer these just to help out noobs a bit :)